# Edit a node via code authentication

Tags: 7

I'm creating a website and I have to give the possibility for an anonymous user to update a node. The node is recognized through the use of a code, code that I am sending to the user when the node is saved for the first time. And when I save this node (for the first time), the node is modified to ensure that it is owned by user X and not by anonymous. Ok, is a little complicated, but these are the requests from my client.

So, I send to the user a mail with this line into: http://DOMINIO.EXT/node/123/edit/codeSHA1.

My problem is that Drupal obviously tells me that access is denied to perform the edit operation (node uid is X, but I'm uid 0) when I click onto that link (in my email client).

How can I resolve this "problem"? I don't want to install TAC or TACLITE, but I can write PHP code into one of my custom module.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using custom coding.

1. Store all hash codes that are the access code to the DB (I think you do this already), a word of caution do not do md5(node id) or sha1(node id) as anyone will be able to figure it out.
2. Enable anonymous users to edit the content type they are submitting where the code is needed to edit the node. I know what this mean, keep reading.
3. Create a custom module where you are going to use the NODE API to intercept the node edit step.

**If Drupal 6:**  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6

```
function YOUR-MODULE-NAME_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'prepare':

    // Add PHP Code here to validate the hash code
    // You can use an if/else condition to print an access denied message
    // if the code is not valid or expired

    break;
  }
}
```

**If Drupal 7:** http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_prepare/7

```
function YOUR-MODULE-NAME_node_prepare($node) {
    // Add PHP Code here to validate the hash code
    // You can use an if/else condition to print an access denied message
    // if the code is not valid or expired
}
```

And that is all.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply, but to create what do you have writed I need to set that all can edit all contents. and this is not so good. Is there a possibility to intercep the function that is called when Drupal intercept a node/X/edit call ? Thanks, M.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the access callback for node/%node/edit with the one you implement in your custom module.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['node/%node/edit'])) {
    $args = !empty($items['node/%node/edit']['access arguments']) ? $items['node/%node/edit']['access arguments'] : array(); 
    $old_callback = $items['node/%node/edit']['access callback'];
    $items['node/%node/edit']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_node_access';
    array_push($args, $old_callback);
    array_push($args, 4);
    $items['node/%node/edit']['access arguments'] = $args;
  }
}

function mymodyle_node_access() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $sha1 = array_pop($args);
  $old_callback = array_pop($args);

  if (!empty($sha1)) {
    // The SHA1 value was passed in the URL.
  }
  else {
    // The user is accessing the edit form without SHA1; let the other callback decide 
    // who can access the node edit form.
    return call_user_func_array($old_callback, $args);
  }
}
```

The code is written as it is to be able to call the previously set access callback without to make any assumption about which callback it is, and how many arguments it requires.
`mymodule_node_access()` must return `TRUE` when the user has access to the node edit form; in your case, the access callback needs to verify the SHA1 value is correct, and return `TRUE` just in that case.